# Integer partitioning in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, permutation, combinations, data-partitioning

Given n ( say 3 people ) and s ( say 100$ ), we'd like to partition s among n people.

So we need all possible n-tuples that sum to s

My Scala code below:

```
def weights(n:Int,s:Int):List[List[Int]] = {
     List.concat( (0 to s).toList.map(List.fill(n)(_)).flatten, (0 to s).toList).
     combinations(n).filter(_.sum==s).map(_.permutations.toList).toList.flatten
}

println(weights(3,100))
```

This works for small values of n. ( n=1, 2, 3 or 4).

Beyond n=4, it takes a very long time, practically unusable.

I'm looking for ways to rework my code using lazy evaluation/ Stream.

My requirements : Must work for n upto 10.

Warning : The problem gets really big really fast. My results from Matlab -

```
---For s =100, n = 1 thru 5 results are ---
n=1 :1 combinations
n=2 :101 combinations
n=3 :5151 combinations
n=4 :176851 combinations
n=5: 4598126 combinations
---
```

Comment: So I guess "fairness" isn't a concern? There would be far fewer combinations if you add constraints on how s may be partitioned.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to actually produce a list of all the combinations...? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to list all 10-tuples that sums to 100 in a normal computer, since the number is too big. However, we can give the count of all 10-tuples.

Comment: Luigi, this is a standard asset allocation problem at most financial institutions. Say you're given s$ and asked to allocate it among n stocks to maximize some metric ( say Sharpe value), you first need to partition the s$. This naive brute-force approach works very well if the number of stocks is small ( below 5 stocks ). Beyond that, we use linear algebraic techniques.

Comment: Strange. If I use my solution to compute the number of combinations, I get the same results up to 3, but things diverge starting with 4.

Comment: @Daniel: I think you just need a dimension for `min` in your memoization table.

Comment: @TravisBrown Now I'm feeling terminally dumb. Yes, I just needed the new dimension. I tried fixing it other ways first, only to have things break in new ways... <sigh>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), or [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Same concept, anyway.

Let's say you have to divide s among n. Recursively, that's defined like this:

```
def permutations(s: Int, n: Int): List[List[Int]] = n match {
  case 0 => Nil
  case 1 => List(List(s))
  case _ => (0 to s).toList flatMap (x => permutations(s - x, n - 1) map (x :: _))
}
```

Now, this will STILL be slow as hell, but there's a catch here... you don't need to recompute `permutations(s, n)` for numbers you have already computed. So you can do this instead:

```
val memoP = collection.mutable.Map.empty[(Int, Int), List[List[Int]]]
def permutations(s: Int, n: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
  def permutationsWithHead(x: Int) = permutations(s - x, n - 1) map (x :: _)

  n match {
    case 0 => Nil
    case 1 => List(List(s))
    case _ => 
      memoP getOrElseUpdate ((s, n), 
                             (0 to s).toList flatMap permutationsWithHead)
  }
}
```

And this can be even further improved, because it will compute every permutation. You only need to compute every combination, and then permute *that* without recomputing.

To compute every combination, we can change the code like this:

```
val memoC = collection.mutable.Map.empty[(Int, Int, Int), List[List[Int]]]
def combinations(s: Int, n: Int, min: Int = 0): List[List[Int]] = {
  def combinationsWithHead(x: Int) = combinations(s - x, n - 1, x) map (x :: _)

  n match {
    case 0 => Nil
    case 1 => List(List(s))
    case _ => 
      memoC getOrElseUpdate ((s, n, min), 
                             (min to s / 2).toList flatMap combinationsWithHead)
  }
}
```

Running `combinations(100, 10)` is still slow, given the sheer numbers of combinations alone. The permutations for each combination can be obtained simply calling `.permutation` on the combination.

Comment: I wouldn't say you _need_ memoization here, right? It's just one possible approach—and one that isn't particularly compatible with a streaming solution.

Comment: More specifically, this approach is going to need many, many gigabytes of memory just for `n = 6`.

Comment: @Travis That depends on what you are trying to optimise for. In my answer, I'm trying to compute everything faster. In yours (very good, by the way), you try to get the first results as fast as possible, and optimise for memory besides.

Comment: @Krishnan I see you accepted my answer after I posted my `combinations` definition. That definition was incorrect. I have fixed it with the present definition, though even combinations alone take very long to compute for s = 100, n = 10.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm going to be using Travis's solution because my particular routine works better with his approach. Your approach optimizes for speed and doesn't optimize for memory, so its very fast for n<5 but for n>5 sometimes my code just crashes ( out of memory errors ). Using Stream, I can manage memory a lot more efficiently, even though computation is slowed down.
btw, the total number of partitions is s+n-1 choose s, in case you are interested in combinatorics...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty `Stream` solution:

```
 def weights(n: Int, s: Int) = (1 until s).foldLeft(Stream(Nil: List[Int])) {
   (a, _) => a.flatMap(c => Stream.range(0, n - c.sum + 1).map(_ :: c))
 }.map(c => (n - c.sum) :: c)
```

It works for `n = 6` in about 15 seconds on my machine:

```
scala> var x = 0
scala> weights(100, 6).foreach(_ => x += 1)
scala> x
res81: Int = 96560646
```

As a side note: by the time you get to `n = 10`, there are [4,263,421,511,271](http://oeis.org/A017764) of these things. That's going to take days just to stream through.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for.I can take it from here and build upon this. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

My solution of this problem, it can computer n till 6:

```
object Partition {
  implicit def i2p(n: Int): Partition = new Partition(n)
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    for(n <- 1 to 6) println(100.partitions(n).size)
  }

}

class Partition(n: Int){
  def partitions(m: Int):Iterator[List[Int]] = new Iterator[List[Int]] {
    val nums = Array.ofDim[Int](m)
    nums(0) = n

    var hasNext = m > 0 && n > 0

    override def next: List[Int] = {
      if(hasNext){
        val result = nums.toList
        var idx = 0
        while(idx < m-1 && nums(idx) == 0) idx = idx + 1
        if(idx == m-1) hasNext = false
        else {
          nums(idx+1) = nums(idx+1) + 1
          nums(0)     = nums(idx) - 1
          if(idx != 0) nums(idx)   = 0
        }
        result
      }
      else Iterator.empty.next
    }
  }
}
```

1
101
5151
176851
4598126
96560646

---

However , we can just show the number of the possible n-tuples:

```
val pt: (Int,Int) => BigInt =  {
    val buf = collection.mutable.Map[(Int,Int),BigInt]()
    (s,n) => buf.getOrElseUpdate((s,n),
        if(n == 0 && s > 0) BigInt(0)
        else if(s == 0) BigInt(1)
        else (0 to s).map{k => pt(s-k,n-1)}.sum
        )
  }

  for(n <- 1 to 20) printf("%2d :%s%n",n,pt(100,n).toString)

 1 :1
 2 :101
 3 :5151
 4 :176851
 5 :4598126
 6 :96560646
 7 :1705904746
 8 :26075972546
 9 :352025629371
10 :4263421511271
11 :46897636623981
12 :473239787751081
13 :4416904685676756
14 :38393094575497956
15 :312629484400483356
16 :2396826047070372396
17 :17376988841260199871
18 :119594570260437846171
19 :784008849485092547121
20 :4910371215196105953021
```

Comment: Sir, you can compute the total number of partitions quite easily, without going through the trouble of first generating them and then counting them. 

(s+n-1) choose s = number of partitions 

So for s = 100, n = 3 people, (100+3-1) choose 100 = 102C100 = 5051.